# Why does the func parameter of TransformedTargetRegressor need to return 2-dimensional array and not 1-dimensional?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-preprocessing

In the documentation of [TransformedTargetRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.TransformedTargetRegressor.html#sklearn.compose.TransformedTargetRegressor), it is mentioned that the parameter `func` needs to return a 2-dimensional array. Should it not be a 1-dimensional array instead? The target y mostly has the shape (n_samples,) which is 1-dimensional.

The below code, where target y and the output of `func` is 1-dimensional, runs properly -

```
exponentiate = lambda x: np.exp(x)
naturalLog = lambda x: np.log(x)
loglinreg = compose.TransformedTargetRegressor(regressor=linear_model.LinearRegression(),func=naturalLog,inverse_func=exponentiate)
loglinreg.fit(X_train,yCO_train)
loglinreg.score(X_train,yCO_train)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/2beed55847ee70d363bdbfe14ee4401438fba057/sklearn/compose/_target.py#L138), `func` is applied using a `FunctionTransformer`, which requires 2-dimensional input.  This also aligns with the other option, setting a `transformer` object directly, which generally expect 2-dimensional input.

See also the Note in [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.TransformedTargetRegressor.html):

> Internally, the target `y` is always converted into a 2-dimensional array to be used by scikit-learn transformers. At the time of prediction, the output will be reshaped to a have the same number of dimensions as `y`.

In your example, it runs because `np.log` and `np.exp` are shape-agnostic; during the fitting, those two functions are actually being called on 2-dimensional arrays.  You can check this by defining your own func:

```py
def mylog(y):
    return np.log(y).ravel()
```

Using that, we get the expected `Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead` error.